# Function on a well-ordered set

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

Let $(W,<)$ be a well ordered set. Let $f : W\rightarrow W$ be a function such that $u < v$ implies $f(u) < f(v)$. Show that $\forall w \in W, w \leq f(w)$.

I was thinking to consider $T=\{x ∈ W | x \leq f(x)\}$
If $T=X$, we are done. 
If not, there $\exists y \in W\setminus T$ such that $f(y) < y$ ($\star$) .

As $y$ was chosen to be the only element in $W\setminus T$, this implies $f(y) \in T$.

Therefore $f(y) \leq f(f(y))$. But from ($\star$) and the properties of the function, $f(f(y))< f(y)$ which is a contradiction.

Is this the correct way of doing the question? I haven't considered the case for if there is more than 1 element in W\T but is that covered from the contradiction?

Any advice would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no justification for your assertion that $y$ is the *only* element of $W\setminus T$. However, you can use the fact that $<$ well-orders $W$ to let $y=\min(W\setminus T)$. Then $f(y)<y$, and the choice of $y$ ensures that $f(y)\in T$, and the rest of your argument is then fine.

Comment: Thanks!  I was wondering where to use the fact that the set was well ordered.

Comment: @user229177: You’re welcome. Picking a smallest counterexample like this is a fairly typical application.